# Android add a ListView inside of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I know it is a very bad practice that "don't put a ListView into a ScrollView" since  ListView has it's own scroll. However, I have couple of other items (buttons and textviews) additional to ListView. For those, I definitely need  to use a ScrollView. I found some solution (http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html) to prevent collapsing the Listview. But, as i said, I need a  ScrollView that encapsulates all items on my XML form. I have added my xml code, Please guide how to achieve this.

```
   <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >  
<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
      </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/longtext" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why not use an `ExpandableListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView by itself is scrollable. Do not put ListView inside a scroll view.

Move your ListView outside scorllview. You can also add a header and footer to the listview.

Check the video by google

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: I know ListView by itself is scrollable. But, after scrolview, I have some other items and they need to be in a scroolview.

Comment: @CoKoder Use the header and footer views.

Comment: @CoKoder add your linear layouts as header and footer to listview.

Comment: I tried to add a footer, but it did not help. Because, my footer has a lot of items and the footer needs a scroll view. so, the thing is that I need to encapsulate not only my listview(it has already own scrolview) but also footer. Do you get my point?

Comment: @Niek, What do you think in this case? So, I need a scroll view in my footer.

Comment: The footer will scroll with the ListView.

Comment: I found the problem. It happens, when i try to use a button click from a button on my footer. How can I use a button that is defined on footer XML file ?

Comment: you need to inflate the view and it as a footer to listview. initialize using the infalted view object and add click listener to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from another post & found it working.

While all other solutions work when **the list-items are of same height**, this solution still provides perfect result **even if the list-items are of variable height**.

Use this customized class in the xml & you are good to go.

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnTouchListener, OnScrollListener {

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Expandable Listview for using the listview inside the scrollview, it will expends the listview as long the content length, create a Custom class with name ExpandableHeightListView

package com.knight.utils;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

After that Programmatically add this line into your code, it will expend the listview in side the scrollview,

```
Listview listview=(Listview)findviewbyid(R.id.listview1);
((ExpandableHeightListView)listview).setExpandable(true);
```